# Getting servers date using FTP

Tags: python, datetime

I'm trying to get the date modified time of a file created on an FTP server using Python, I am currently using the ftputil external library and doing the following:

```
file_folder_time_stamp = time.strftime('%y%m%d%H%M%S', time.gmtime(host.path.getmtime(dir_or_file)))
```

Unfortunately, the return time I get is for the year 2013. Instead of 2014. I've made sure the server running the FTP server is updated to the current time. Doing a date command on the terminal, ensures I get the right time. Am I just parsing something incorrectly then?

I create a folder, and check the time of creating using the getmtime command, and it still returns a string such as 13090810000. This should instead look like 140908xxxx

Comment: Any reason you're not using `datetime.fromtimestamp` - anyway - are you *sure* that the file's modification date isn't indeed in 2013?

Comment: Yes, I'm 100% sure it has not been created in 2013. I confirmed this by creating a folder, and instaneously checking the time modified, and it does return 2013 as well.

I only wanted to get the YYMMDDHHMMSS format, so I could do a quick comparison, as to how old the folder was. Thus, I am using the time.strftime function.

Answer (score 4):

What epoch-time do you get from `host.path.getmtime(dir_or_file)`? What do you get from `time.gmtime(...)`? To check time differences you can substract two dates to get a `datetime.timedelta` object, and probably save some troubles with transformations:

```
from datetime import datetime
from ftputil import FTPHost

URL = "ftp.sample.org"

with FTPHost(URL, "anonymous", "xbello@sample.org") as host:
    mod_time = host.path.getmtime("robots.txt")

    dif = datetime.now() - datetime.fromtimestamp(mod_time)

    print dif.seconds
```

Comment: Thanks Xbello. For the moment, I don't have access to a robots.txt file, as I am not in the root directory and placing myself inside a sub-directory. What I do, is create a folder, get its modified time, and deleted it right away. This gives me the "server" time. After that, I compare it with the modified time of another file/folder and do a comparison as you have mentioned. Weirdly, I get 2013 for the created folder, and if I upload a server manually usually, I get a time stamp of 2014. I'm definitely puzzled as to why this is happening ...

Comment: This is the epoch time, I get when I just run host.path.getmtime(dir_name) : **1378670940.0**

Comment: ftputil have an utility called `synchronize_times()` that creates a file in the remote server and uses its creation time to sync. Does it work to you?

Comment: xbello. Thanks, I had looked into that, but the error I get is that **ftputil.ftp_error.TimeShiftError: time shift (-31521628.26 s) > 1 day**

Comment: I set up a ftp server here to test, and everything runs fine! Might be related to your ftp-server software? (I used vsftpd).

Comment: I believe if the sync shift is greater than a certain threshold it fails. Which is the case for me (~1 year) ...

Comment: I guess, this post clarifies the issue I am facing: http://ftputil.sschwarzer.net/trac/ticket/55?version=0. I don't really want to set the time_shift variable to a random number, because that might be server specific ...